# cocos2d : CCsprite setVisible method not working

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

In an cocos 2d game i user 3 heart sprites to update lives of hero.If hero lost one life..one heart should be hided.

I use below code but its not working properly.please help me.

```
- (void)updateLives {
    int i = _lives;
    [self livess:(int)i];
}

- (void)livess:(int)ii { 

    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    heart1=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"heart.png"];
    heart2=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"heart.png"];
    heart3=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"heart.png"];
    [heart1 setPosition:ccp(winSize.width/2*1.3, winSize.height * 0.9)];
    [self addChild:heart1 z:0];
    [heart2 setPosition:ccp(winSize.width/2*1.1, winSize.height * 0.9)];
    [self addChild:heart2 z:0];
    [heart3 setPosition:ccp(winSize.width/2*0.9, winSize.height * 0.9)];
    [self addChild:heart3 z:0];


    if (ii==3) {

        NSLog(@"%d",ii);
    }
    else if (ii==2)
    {
        NSLog(@"%d",ii);

        [heart3 setVisible:NO];

    } else if (ii==1)
    {

        NSLog(@"%d",ii);

        [heart3 setVisible:NO];
        [heart2 setVisible:NO];
    }
    else
    {

    }         
}
```

note:in above code..nslog is printing correct values ..for example 1,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should hide correctly from your code. However, if this updateLives is called inside the game loop, probably the reason you see it is not hided as you expected is the heart from the previous frame. Try

1) creating the heart1, heart2, heart3 once

2) in the update, don't create the sprite. i.e. keep only if... else part of your code there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks man worked...you got only one reputation but you rock ;)